# String decode to Json in php

Tags: php, json

Hi I have a api call that returns a string like the following, and I need to convert it in a JSON object to process.

```
"a:1:{s:19:\"is_featured_service\";b:0;}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a `serialize()`d string. `unserialize()` it, then `json_encode()` it:

```
<?php
$string = "a:1:{s:19:\"is_featured_service\";b:0;}";
$json = json_encode(unserialize($string));
var_dump($json);
```

Be careful, though. Per PHP manual:

> **Warning** Do not pass untrusted user input to unserialize() regardless
>   of the options value of allowed_classes. Unserialization can result in
>   code being loaded and executed due to object instantiation and
>   autoloading, and a malicious user may be able to exploit this. Use a
>   safe, standard data interchange format such as JSON (via json_decode()
>   and json_encode()) if you need to pass serialized data to the user.

- [Demo](https://3v4l.org/DqB1r)
- [serialize() reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)
- [unserialize() reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)